# Importing a txt file into Matlab and reading the data

Tags: matlab, matrix

I need to import a .txt datafile into Matlab. The file has been made into 3 columns. Each column has specific numbers for a given variable. The script code must be able to do the following,

***Requirement***

1) import the data from txt into Matlab

2) Matlab should remove the values from the columns if the values are out of a certain range

3) Matlab should tell which line and what type of error.

***My Approach***

I have tried using the following approach,

```
function data = insertData(filename)
filename = input('Insert the name of the file: ', 's');
data = load(filename);

Column1 = data(:,1);
Column2 = data(:,2);
Column3 = data(:,3);

%Ranges for each column
nclm1 = Column1(Column1>0);
nclm2 = Column2(Column2 >= 10 & Column2 <= 100);
nclm3 = Column3(Column3>0);

%Final new data columns within the ranges
final = [nclm1, nclm2, nclm3];

end
```

***Problem***

The above code has the following problems:

1) Matlab is not saving the imported data as 'data' after the user inserts the name of the file. Hence I don't know why my code is wrong.

```
filename =input('Insert the name of the file: ', 's');
    data = load(filename);
```

2) The columns in the end do not have the same dimensions because I can see that Matlab removes values from the columns independently. Therefore is there a way in which I can make Matlab remove values/rows from a matrix rather than the three 'vectors', given a range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)  Not sure what you mean by this.  I created a sample text file and Matlab imports the data as `data` just fine.  However, you are only returning the original unfiltered data so maybe that is what you mean???  I modified it to return the original data and the filtered data.

2) You need to `or` the bad indices together so that they are removed from each column like this.  Note I made some other edits ... see comments in the code below:

```
function [origData, filteredData]= insertData(filename)
% You pass in filename then overwrite it ... 
% Modified to only prompt if not passed in.
if ~exist('filename','var') || isempty(filename) 
    filename = input('Insert the name of the file: ', 's');        
end
origData = load(filename);

% Ranges check for each column
% Note: return these if you want to know what data was filter for 
% which reason
badIdx1 = origData(:,1) > 0;
badIdx2 = origData(:,2) >= 10 & origData(:,2) <= 100;
badIdx3 = origData(:,3)>0;

totalBad = badIdx1 | badIdx2 | badIdx3;

%Final new data columns within the ranges
filteredData = origData(~totalBad,:);

end
```

Note: you mentioned you want to know which line for which type of error.   That information is now contained in `badIDx1`,2, 3.  So you can return them, print a message to the screen, or whatever you need to display that information.